# Relationship problem UserRoles-Roles ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

My solution is in `ASP.NET Core 2.1` and was working. Now I've problem doing this:

```
var user = _context.Users
                    .Include(u => u.Function)
                    .Include(u=>u.Roles)
                    .ThenInclude(r=>r.Role)
```

My user get his roles (`ApplicationUserRole` class), but when I look at these roles, `RoleId`, `UserId` and `User` are set, but `Role` object is `null`.

My classes are :

```
public class SSTRNRole : IdentityRole<string>
{
    public SSTRNRole() { }
    public SSTRNRole(string name, string type, string description, bool isChoosable)
        : this()
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Type = type;
        this.Description = description;
        this.IsChoosable = isChoosable;
    }
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsChoosable { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation property for the users in this role.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> Users { get; } = new List<ApplicationUserRole>();
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual SSTRNUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual SSTRNRole Role { get; set; }
}

public class SSTRNUSer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation property for the roles this user belongs to.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> Roles { get; } = new List<ApplicationUserRole>();
}
```

and my `DbContext` configuration (for roles) is:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    #region UserRoles

    builder.Entity<SSTRNRole>()
        .HasMany(ur => ur.Users)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.RoleId)
        .IsRequired();

    builder.Entity<SSTRNUser>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Roles)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
        .IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(b =>
    {
        b.HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId });
        b.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
            .WithMany(r => r.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
            .IsRequired();
        b.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
            .WithMany(r => r.Roles)
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
            .IsRequired();

        b.ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
    });

    #endregion

    #region Roles

    builder.Entity<SSTRNRole>(b =>
    {
        b.HasKey(r => r.Id);
        b.HasIndex(r => r.NormalizedName).HasName("RoleNameIndex").IsUnique();
        b.ToTable("AspNetRoles");
        b.Property(r => r.ConcurrencyStamp).IsConcurrencyToken();

        b.Property(u => u.Name).HasMaxLength(256);
        b.Property(u => u.NormalizedName).HasMaxLength(256);

        b.HasMany(r => r.Users).WithOne().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId).IsRequired();
        //b.HasMany(r => r.Functions).WithOne().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId).IsRequired();
    });
}
```

I tried reverting/deleting last migrations but nothing.

Comment: Can you try adding the `.ToList()` call to your DB request? Loading the entities in memory could help.